# Use GRASS through R

Tags: grass-gis, r

I want to use GRASS GIS 7 through R 3.1.3 in kubuntu operational system. Could someone help me connect GRASS with R, and use GRASS commands through R (not the other way round!).

Comment: look at [GRASS wiki: R statistics](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/R_statistics)

Comment: Yes, I have looked into it. Still, I would need some clearer instructions!

Comment: Show us what you tried, and where you got stuck, and then we can try and get you past that. Have you installed `rgrass7`?

Comment: yo can also use [spgrass6](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spgrass6/index.html)

Comment: Note that *the other way round* you refer to is just starting R in GRASS GIS (i.e. from command line inside GRASS session). This will save you from calling `initGRASS()` but the rest should be the same (you are still using `execGRASS()` and others to call GRASS modules etc.

Answer (score 17):

Here is a quick worked example of setting the GRASS environment, reading an on-disk raster, calculating a focal mean (using r.neighbors) and reading the results back into R. Hopefully this will get you started.

```
if (!require(rgrass7)) stop("rgrass7 PACKAGE MISSING")

setwd("D:/TMP") # Working directory 

# Set on-disk raster variable
rname <- paste(getwd(), "elev.img", sep="/")

# Set GRASS environment and database location 
loc <- initGRASS("C:/Program Files (x86)/GRASS GIS 7.0.0", 
       home=getwd(), gisDbase="GRASS_TEMP", override=TRUE )

# Import raster to GRASS and set region
execGRASS("r.in.gdal", flags="o", parameters=list(input=rname, output="tmprast"))
execGRASS("g.region", parameters=list(raster="tmprast") ) 

# Calculate 9x9 focal mean 
execGRASS("r.neighbors", flags="overwrite", parameters=list(input="tmprast", output="xxfm", 
          method="average", size=as.integer(9)) )

r <- readRAST("xxfm")
  spplot(r)
```

Comment: When you end (`stop()`) after unsuccessful `require()`, `library()` might be more appropriate.

Comment: works like a charm. if anybody searches for linux path to grass executable: ->  /usr/lib/grass72 if you have 7.2 installed. otherwise check with grass<<your version here>> --config path. Note that you need grass-dev package installed as well.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you very much for your responses!
Eventually, is very very easy to work with GRASS GIS through R.
After you have created in GRASS the location and mapset in which you wish to work, you can type in the GRASS shell: "rstudio &"
"&" Helps for working simultaneously in both GRASS GIS and R. Otherwise, the GRASS shell would switch to R.
And that is for Linux!